Why I am getting a late Initialization error in Flutter even after assigning data
Why I am getting a late Initialization error, even after setting data and using setState method?
I have assigned a value of selectCity inside onPressed function of elevated button where select location is a text.
I am new to Flutter, help is appreciated.

This is my code:
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:geocode/geocode.dart';

class FirstLocationAccess extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstLocationAccess({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstLocationAccess> createState() => _FirstLocationAccessState();
}

class _FirstLocationAccessState extends State<FirstLocationAccess> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mQSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var mQHeight = mQSize.height;
    var mQWidth = mQSize.width;
    late String? selectCity;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: mQHeight / 6),
            Center(
              child: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, size: mQHeight / 10),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: mQHeight / 25),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                var location = await _determinePosition();
                var lat = location.latitude;
                var long = location.longitude;
                try {
                  List<Placemark> placemark =
                      await placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, long);
                  String? setSelectCity = await placemark[0].locality;

                  setState(() {
                    selectCity = setSelectCity;
                  });
                  print(selectCity);
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e);
                }
              },
              child: const Text("Select Location"),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: mQHeight / 25),
            Text(selectCity!),
            SizedBox(height: mQHeight / 25),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Continue')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


because selectCity is inside build() method. So, when setState is called it triggers the build() method and selectCity gets reinitialized with null. to fix this, put the selectCity outside the build() method. and in Text() widget add null-aware: selectCity ?? ""
class FirstLocationAccess extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstLocationAccess({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstLocationAccess> createState() => _FirstLocationAccessState();
}

class _FirstLocationAccessState extends State<FirstLocationAccess> {

  String? selectCity; //here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mQSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var mQHeight = mQSize.height;
    var mQWidth = mQSize.width;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: mQHeight / 6),
            Center(
              child: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, size: mQHeight / 10),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: mQHeight / 25),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                var location = await _determinePosition();
                var lat = location.latitude;
                var long = location.longitude;
                try {
                  List<Placemark> placemark =
                      await placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, long);
                  String? setSelectCity = await placemark[0].locality;

                  setState(() {
                    selectCity = setSelectCity;
                  });
                  print(selectCity);
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e);
                }
              },
              child: const Text("Select Location"),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: mQHeight / 25),
            Text(selectCity ?? "") //and add this,
            SizedBox(height: mQHeight / 25),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Continue')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


the late keyword also needs to be removed

thanks! , ps Late keyword should be removed also.

Text(selectCity!), is accessing selectCity before you assign it a value and that only happens when you press the button.

Try Text(selectCity??'') instead of Text(selectCity!)
